# MS Teams Notification Bot installations are not persisted in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-notificationbot?tabs=vscode) to build a notification bot in Teams.

I added a blob storage as described [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/blob/1e1c86c6f294012438474bb2f806e307d607c47b/adaptive-card-notification/README.md#optional-use-azure-blob-storage-to-persist-notification-connections).

The blob storage container is created automatically, however it remains empty.

My code:
[image]

-> When I try to send notifications via /api/notification endpoint, 0 bot installations are returned, no notifications are sent, although I installed the bot in MS teams.

Any ideas how to debug the bot installations / azure blob storage connection?

Comment: What are the versions of your packages?

Comment: "dependencies": {
        "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.9.0",
        "@microsoft/adaptivecards-tools": "^1.0.0",
        "@microsoft/teamsfx": "^2.0.0",
        "botbuilder": "^4.18.0",
        "restify": "^10.0.0"
    },

Comment: I don't see any obviously incompatible versions, so maybe you could try [debugging with ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-channel-ngrok?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Answer (score 0):

Setting my Azure AD app registration to multi-tenant did the trick for me:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/how-to-create-an-app-registration-in-azure-ad-for-a-bot-solution/ba-p/810761